# Convenient way to convert dataframe to vector of tuple?

Tags: dataframe, tuples, julia

I'm trying to make a function that converts dataframe to vector of tuples in Julia.

For example,

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A=1:4, B=4:7, C=10:13)

4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      4     10
   2 │     2      5     11
   3 │     3      6     12
   4 │     4      7     13

T = [t for t in zip(df.A, df.B, df.C)]

T = 4-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 4, 10)
 (2, 5, 11)
 (3, 6, 12)
 (4, 7, 13)
```

Then T becomes the result what I exactly wanted.

The problem is, however, that I need to functionalize above process.

So, what I need is to automatically put columns of dataframe into the zip function.

The form of function that I want to make is as below

```
using DataFrames

function DataframeToTuple(df)
    T = [t for t in zip(df.first column name, df.second column name, ... df.last column name)]
    return T
end
```

Is there any convenient way? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is perhaps the shortest way:

```
julia> Tuple.(eachrow(df))
4-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 4, 10)
 (2, 5, 11)
 (3, 6, 12)
 (4, 7, 13)
```

It is also quite interesting to know that you can convert a `DataFrame` to a `Vector` of `NamedTuple`s in an identical way:

```
julia> NamedTuple.(eachrow(df))
4-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:A, :B, :C), Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}}:
 (A = 1, B = 4, C = 10)
 (A = 2, B = 5, C = 11)
 (A = 3, B = 6, C = 12)
 (A = 4, B = 7, C = 13)
```

Comment: Same solution with the pipe operator:

`eachrow(df) .|> NamedTuple`

I personally find this more human readable

Answer (score 5):

A more efficient way to convert a data frame to a vector of `NamedTuple` if it is not very wide (roughly less than 1000 columns) is:

```
julia> Tables.rowtable(df)
4-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:A, :B, :C), Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}}:
 (A = 1, B = 4, C = 10)
 (A = 2, B = 5, C = 11)
 (A = 3, B = 6, C = 12)
 (A = 4, B = 7, C = 13)
```

and if you insist on tuple then do `Tuple.(Tables.rowtable(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of doing this - inevitably, it will involve `Tuple` or `NamedTuple.`

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A=1:4, B=4:7, C=10:13)

4×3 DataFrame
Row │ A      B      C     
    │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
────┼─────────────────────
  1 │     1      4     10
  2 │     2      5     11
  3 │     3      6     12
  4 │     4      7     13

[Tuple(df[n,:]) for n in 1:size(df,1)]

4-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
(1, 4, 10)
(2, 5, 11)
(3, 6, 12)
(4, 7, 13)
```

The reason why is interesting. As a basic idea, there are two kinds of type, simple values and collections. An example of the former is `String`, and examples of the latter is `Tuple` and `Array`. Type names start with a capital letter.

For every type, there is a corresponding function, with the same name as the type, but the name is all lower-case. Type `String` has function `string`, `Tuple` has function `tuple`. The function takes the data and puts it into the new type. If the new type is a simple type then a conversion is done, if a collection then the data is put into a new collection without conversion.

```
 # String
 string(1.0)       # -> "1.0"
 string(1:3)       # -> "1:3"

 # Tuple
 tuple(1.0)        # -> (1.0,)
 tuple(1:3)        # -> (1:3,) 
 tuple([1,2,3,4])  # -> ([1, 2, 3, 4],)
```

For collections only, another function is provided which has the same name as the type, complete with a capital letter at the start. This does the conversion.

```
 # Tuple
 Tuple(1.0)       # -> (1.0,)
 Tuple(1:3)       # -> (1,2,3)
 Tuple([1,2,3,4]) # -> (1,2,3,4)
```

Hence here, when converting to tuples we have to use the function `Tuple` (or the function `NamedTuple`).

Comment: This paragraph "For every type, there is a corresponding function, with the same name as the type, but the name is all lower-case.  ... If the new type is a simple type then a conversion is done, if a collection then the data is put into a new collection without conversion." It is **not** at all correct. `string` and `String` are largely unrelated `string` is a shorthand for `print`ing to a buffer and reading vtgat off into a `String`. `tuple(x,y,z)` and `(x,y, z)` are the same thing the `tuple` name is largely to provide a function form of putting brackets around things to use with map etc

Comment: Great! Thank a lot